# How to set CommView to capture a specific wifi instead of the whole channel?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, sniffing

I am trying to experiment with CommView for Wifi. When I start searching for devices their are separated in channels.

I click on the one I want and then Capture. As I see the program is capturing the whole channel, not only the one wifi I want.

This leads to tremendous lost time because of low packets captured. So my question is, is there any way to make it possible to capture only one wifi instead of all the wifi in the channel ?

Comment: Are you asking how to use "filters" (aka "rules")?

Comment: @sawdust maybe, I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup a **rule** to *capture* packets based on the *MAC address* of the WiFi access point you're interested in.

[CommView for WiFi: Rules](http://www.tamos.com/htmlhelp/commwifi/rules.htm)